# How to store file paths from a tab separated text file in a bash array

Tags: bash, awk, carriage-return

I have a tab separated text file with one column of file paths, e.g. `table.txt`

```
> SampleID  Factor  Condition   Replicate   Treatment   Type    Dataset isPE    ReadLength  isREF   PathFASTQ
> DG13  fd3 c1  1   cc  0   0102    0   50  1   "/path/to/fastq"
> DG14  fd3 c1 1    cc  1   0102    0   50  1   "/path/to/fastq"
```

I would like to store the paths in a bash array so I can use these in a downstream parallel computation (SGE Task Arrays). For simplicity, the leading and trailing `"` can easily be not included in `table.txt`.

Excluding the header line, I tried the following:

```
files=($(awk '{ if(($8 == 0)) { print $1} }' table.txt ))    
paths=($(awk '{ if(($8 == 0)) { print $11} }' table.txt ))
infile="${paths[$SGE_TASK_ID]}"/"${files[$SGE_TASK_ID]}".fastq.gz
```

`$SGE_TASK_ID` takes a user-defined integer value between (1-N) in case someone does not know.

Unfortunately `$infile` does not show the expected value for `$SGE_TASK_ID=1`:

```
/path/to/fastq/DG13.fastq.gz
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, this code will remove Control M characters during run of the code.

```
myarr=($(awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} match($NF,/\/[^"]*/){\
         val=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH);\
         num=split(val,array,"/");\
         print val"/"$1"."array[num]".gz"}'  Input_file))
for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

In case you want to remove control M characters from your Input_file itself then try running following too:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

When we print array with loop as above shown, output will be as follows.

```
/path/to/fastq/DG13.fastq.gz
/path/to/fastq/DG14.fastq.gz
```

***Explanation of `awk` code:***

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
match($NF,/\/[^"]*/){                 ##Using match function of awk program here, match everything till " in last field.
  val=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)      ##Creating variable val which is sub-string where starting point is RSTART till value of RLENGTH.
  num=split(val,array,"/")            ##Creating variable num whose value is number of elements plitted by split, splitting val into array with / is delimiter.
  print val"/"$1"."array[num]".gz"    ##Printing val / first field DOT array last element then .gz here.
}
'  Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
while read -r -a ary; do
    ((nr++)) || continue                # skip header line
    if (( ${ary[7]} == 0 )); then       # if "isPE" == 0 ..
        path=${ary[10]#\"}              # remove leading double-quote
        path=${path%\"}                 # remove trailing double-quote
        file=${ary[0]}
        infile[$((++SGE_TASK_ID))]="${path}/${file}.fastq.gz"
    fi
done < table.txt

echo "${infile[1]}"
echo "${infile[2]}"
```

Output:

```
/path/to/fastq/DG13.fastq.gz
/path/to/fastq/DG14.fastq.gz
```